# What to I need to do to on my server to communicate with an Android app?

Tags: java, php, android, client-server

I am currently writing and Android app, and I need to do some stuff with a server. Actually I just don't know where to begin, since I don't know very much about server side.

My Android app will send Java objects and images to my server, so what do I need to write or use on my server ? Is it possible to write Java code instead of `PHP` on the server side ?

Could you please give me the steps to prepare my server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write Java code instead of PHP on the server side ?

You can use any programming language you like for server side programming. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp) provides some useful information on various Java based approaches using the HTTP protocol.

> will send Java objects

You will need to serialise them to a data format. JSON and XML are popular for transmitting structured data across HTTP.

> and images to my server

HTTP allows the transmission of files and [Java can construct the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314300/how-to-simply-generate-post-http-request-from-java-to-do-the-file-upload).

Comment: Thanks, I will try with what you gave me :) I've already wrote in the past a server that displays a webapp with JSP and Servlets. What is the difference between this and writing a program on a server for an Android app ?

Comment: Ok ! So I just need to write some servlets that use Gson for example to format a JSON file ?

Comment: What kind of project do I create in Eclipse ? A "Dynamic Web Project" like I did for my webapp ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you just want to communicate between the server and client(Android). I would recommend considering REST style web service for your server, where you can use either JSON (recommended) or XML format.

[How to implement REST in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701260/how-to-implement-rest-in-a-web-aplication)